# There is no windowbuilder in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I need to make a JFrame for my JDBC connection, but there is no windowbuilder in Eclipse. When I want to install the windowbuilder, it says all items are installed.

[image: trying to install]

[image: no windowbuilder]

Can anyone help me ignore this warning? Thanks!

Comment: then it is installed, you just can't find it..

Comment: @EugeneSh. anyway to find it?

Comment: I don't have it, but I would imagine that it is adding some new items into the "New..." menu.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: @E-Riz Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: Have you tried it with the version of Eclipse from that date, *Mars*? Which version of Java are you using to run Eclipse?

Comment: @nitind no I didnt. can I use Mars? i thought i should just use Luna. java version is 1.8.0, and jre 8.

Comment: @nitind Thanks a lot:) I just installed that Mars version and it worked:)

Comment: Try looking through the "Other ..." option